# assigning char pointer to char and char array variable

Tags: c, pointers, char

Why is the following ok?

```
    char *a;
    char b[]="asdf";
    a=b;
```

But the following is not?

```
    char a[10];
    char b[]="asdf";
    a=b;
```

The above gives error: incompatible types in assignment.

Comment: I find it unlikely that you aren't at least getting some warnings with your first example. Could you post the complete output from your compiler?

Answer (score 1):

Both are not ok.

Maybe you were attempting ,

```
char *a;
char b[]="asdf";
a=b;
```

Comment: Actually, the first one is legal, but it's probably not what's intended.

Comment: @CongXu , yes ,these beginneres must know ,all that compiles , is not right !!

Comment: It can be "right". For example if 'a' were a pointer to int it would be an acceptable practice. The fact that it compiles without a warning likely indicates that there is rationale to allow the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

```
char a;
char b[]="asdf";
a=b;
```

Here you are assigning address of array `b` to `a` which is of `char` type. Size of address will be 4 bytes (8 bytes in 64 bit m/c) which you are assigning to 1 byte `char` variable `a` so the values will get truncated. This is legal but its of no use.

I think you are actually trying to assign first character of `b` array to `a`. In that case do `a = b[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

The value of an array evaluates to the address of the first element within the array. So basically, it's a constant value. That's why when you try to do a=b in the second example, you're trying to do something similar to 2=7, only you have two addresses instead of 2 integers.

Now it makes sense that the first example would work, since assigning an address to a pointer is a valid operation.

Answer (score -1):

You need to include the below header for string library.

`#include <string.h>`

Using `strcpy(strX, strY);` will copy string Y into string X, given there is enough space.

Comment: `strcpy()` does **not** check that there is enough space available, in fact it has no way to do so. You can use `strncpy()` to control that you don't buffer overflow, but you may have to insert the final null byte manually.