# string input parameter for c program

Tags: c

I wrote a function to replace the blank spaces with tab character. But when I tried to implement it using function. I am quite not understanding how to call this function. I need functions

1. Which takes string from user as input,
2. Second function which replaces the blank space with tab character,
3. Function to print the modified string.

I achieved second one:

```c
void SecondFunction()
{
     char string[] = "I am new to c";
     char *p = string;

     for (; *p; ++p)
     {
         if (*p == ' ')
             *p = '\t';
     }
     printf(string);
}
```

And when I tried to call this function like:

```c
int main()
{
     SecondFunction("Hi s"); 
}
```

By changing my function to:

```c
void SecondFunction(char* str)
{
    char string[] = str;
    char *p = string;
    ....
    ...etc
}
```

I get the following error:

```
 error: invalid initializer
   char string[] = str;
   ^
```

Please, can anybody help me to write the 3 functions of my requirement?

Comment: You can't assign `char string[] = str;` You could do `char *string = str;` but you don't need it. Just do `char *p = str;`.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15424096/4403123).

Comment: i did like void SecondFunction(char* str)   {   char *p = str; ...bla bla .. printf(str);} It is giving error as "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Comment: @AjayPhilia you use user input string, not string literal.

Comment: `strcpy` is what you want.

Comment: You get a +1 for being honest

Comment: instead of `printf(string)` you should do `printf("%s", string)`; should your input value have `%` characters, your program would have undefined behaviour.

Comment: Rather than `printf("%s", string)`, you should use `fputs(string, stdout)`.

Comment: But note that the while it is actually important to use either `printf("%s, string)` or `fputs`, which of the two to use is mostly a matter of style.  `fputs` is slightly more efficient at runtime, but a reasonable argument can be made for using `printf`.  However, `printf(string)` is a horrible thing to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. **Reading user input**

   To read input from the user you can use [`scanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/). You need to pass it the *memory address* of the variable where you want to store the input:

   ```
   char userinput[256]; // make it large enough to hold what the user inputs
   scanf("%s", userinput); // array decays to pointer so no '&' here
   ```

   The `%s` means were reading string input. We could also read an `int` using `%d`, like this:

   ```
   int i;
   scanf("%d", &i); // note the address-of operator '&' to get the address of i
   ```
2. **Printing variables**

   Your `SecondFunction` is almost correct. To `printf` a C-string you need to use a syntax similar to when you `scanf` to a variable:

   ```
   printf("%s", string);
   ```

   Similarly, you could print the `int i` like this:

   ```
   printf("The number is: %d", i);
   ```
3. **Copying C-strings**

   When you tried doing this: `char string[] = str`, that's not possible. Arrays cannot be assigned or even copy constructed.

   Just in case for the future, when you want to copy a C-string, you need to use [`strcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/):

   ```
   char string[256]; // again, must be large enough to hold the new contents
   strcpy(string, str); // copies from str to string
   ```

   So in conclusion, your function could look something like this:

   ```
   void SecondFunction(char* str)
   {
       char string[256];
       strcpy(string, str);
       char *p = string;
       for (; *p; ++p)
       {
           if (*p == ' ')
               *p = '\t';
       }
       printf("%s", string);
   }
   ```

   **Bonus:** Why you can't write to the `str` parameter directly

   When you write this: `SecondFunction("Hi s")`, the string `"Hi s"` gets stored in a *read-only* memory segment.

   If you then go and try to modify the parameter inside `SecondFunction`, you get *undefined behavior*, possibly a segmentation fault.